# ASP.NET MVC 3 on Mono - MVC app versus WebForms

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, apache, mono

I got Mono installed and set up running underneath Apache. I was able to add in a index.aspx page and a web.config into the root directory and get this to work. Now deploying a MVC 3 app to the root directory, a default / request pulls back the generic Apache 2 Test Page.

What do you need to do to enable MVC apps? Specifically MVC 3?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [section "ASP.NET MVC3 Support" in thr release notes for Mono 2.10](http://www.mono-project.com/Release_Notes_Mono_2.10#ASP.NET_MVC3_Support).

Apparently you need to copy some assemblies from MVC 3 into your `bin` directory and delete one.
Quote from the link:

> **Running Razor, MVC3 and WebPages**
>
> To get this stack running, you will need to copy Microsoft's MVC3
>   libraries into your bin directory:
>
> - System.Web.Mvc.dll
> - System.Web.Razor.dll
> - System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll
> - System.Web.WebPages.dll
> - System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll
>
> It is very
>   important that you remove the Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll from
>   the bin directory for the above to work.

Comment: What is the best resource for what the httpd.conf section for an MVC 3 app should look like? +1