# Run Ext .Net on Linux

Tags: .net, linux, apache

Is it possible to run application written in Ext .Net on Linux OS with Apache? 
I know I can use Mono for developing .Net application on Linux, but does it support Ext .Net?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC 3 on Mono - MVC app versus WebForms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8857244/asp-net-mvc-3-on-mono-mvc-app-versus-webforms)